# Tweepy - Skip following accounts that are private

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I have a Twitter bot which is working great. However, I have encountered an issue when it comes to following users which have a private Twitter account.

The bot will send a follow request, and then keep sending the follow request even though a request has already been sent.

Is it possible to skip following back accounts that are private?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
#followback.py

import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api
import time

def get_friends():
    # gets a list of your followers and following
    followers = api.followers_ids(screen_name)
    following = api.friends_ids(screen_name)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def follow_followers(api):
    logger.info("Retrieving and following followers...")
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
        if not follower.following:
            try:
                logger.info("Now following "+ (follower.screen_name))
                follower.follow()
            except tweepy.TweepError as error:
                if error.api_code == 160:
                    logger.info("Already sent a follow request to " + (follower.screen_name) + ". Attempting to skip.")

def main():
    api = create_api()
    while True:
        follow_followers(api)
        logger.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have now added some code:

```
if error.api_code == 160:
    logger.info("Already sent a follow request to " + (follower.screen_name) + ".
```

Which catches the error and looks neater in the log, but it is filling the log up with:

```
INFO:root:Retrieving and following followers...
INFO:root:Now following "user a"
INFO:root:Already sent a follow request to "user a". Attempting to skip.
INFO:root:Now following "user b"
INFO:root:Already sent a follow request to "user b". Attempting to skip.
INFO:root:Waiting...
INFO:root:Retrieving and following followers...
INFO:root:Now following "user a"
INFO:root:Already sent a follow request to "user a". Attempting to skip.
INFO:root:Now following "user b"
INFO:root:Already sent a follow request to "user b". Attempting to skip.
INFO:root:Waiting...
```

Both user a and user b in this example are private accounts.

Let me know if you require any further information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `protected` attribute of each [User object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user), e.g. `if not follower.protected:`.